# What is including a sound from another movie as a tribute called?

Tags: film-techniques

Is there a term for when a movie intentionally includes a bit of a sound track from another movie solely as a tribute to the original movie?

Comment: a homage?  https://www.google.com/#hl=en&biw=1427&bih=580&sclient=psy-ab&q=define:+homage&oq=define:+homage&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i10j0l2.1193.4210.0.4585.14.14.0.0.0.0.486.2502.0j8j0j1j2.11.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.KL5O8zxkjF4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2U&fp=2e81abdf57559006

Comment: @DForck42 **An** homage?

Comment: @M6rk not only would the question be much better with an example, it would also make answering it much easier.

Comment: @keen :-P was thinking H, not O.

Comment: @DForck42 *Sacre bleu!*

Comment: I seem to have hijacked this person's question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Such a gesture could be called a *[homage](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Homage)* or a *[shout-out](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShoutOut)* depending, as TV Tropes notes, on how elaborate it is:

> *Homage* (literally, an honor or tribute) is the deliberate, but respectful, recreation of one work of fiction within the context of another. Usually this is done for comedic effect, but occasionally it is serious. Sometimes it's both. A *Homage* is an extended sequence, significantly more than a simple *Shout Out*, but does not actually constitute a *Cross Over* ...

I'm unaware of anything used specifically for homages involving soundtracks in films. Besides *tribute* and the above-mentioned terms, I've also come *hat-tip* or *tipping one's hat* used with similar connotations.